# Random black line appearing on glass texture from interaction of noise & fresnel node

Tags: texturing

Removing noise makes it go away somehow.
[image: Removing noise makes it go away somehow.]
Without noise
[image: .]
Glass nodes
[image: Glass nodes]

The background is HDRI

Comment: Your texture has no texture coordinates, and you can't just plug a factor value to a normal input. Match socket colors

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you probably need a  Bump node between the Noise and the Fresnel Normal - to generate a bumpy surface. The same Normal should be used for the Glossy and Diffuse shaders also.

Comment: the goal was to make the glass wobbly, but the wobble only being apparent the shallower the view angle. This is so that next to the window you wont see the wobble in front of you but it is visible farther along due to the change in view angle.

Comment: i added a bump node between them & the effect seems to not work (similar to removing noise node)

Comment: The noise should connect to the Height of the bump node, not the Normal. As mentioned by Duarte you shouldn’t mix node types. The line is a result of the corrupt normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this :

[image: weird glass]

The Bump node uses the Noise to generate a Normal for the shaders. The 'bumpiness' can be adjusted via the Distance of the bump node. The Layer Weight node can be adjusted to vary the amount the angle with the glass affects the bumpiness (so shallower angles appear more bumpy while 'straight on' viewing is effectively flat).

Note that this is obviously a non-physically based material (since the bumpiness is directly affected by the viewing angle).

Comment: So this worked, but apparently i found your original suggestion also worked and had a better effect in my scene; it didn't appear for me initially because it changed the object's sensitivity to noise scale somehow (making it unnoticable). Anyways I tweaked the value & the texture seems fixed!

[First solution](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/314360555265720321/464367895443406848/unknown.png?width=1085&height=619)

[This answer](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/314360555265720321/464368614175145984/unknown.png?width=1074&height=618)